# Updating my about me on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, status-completed, account-recovery

Every time I try updating my about me, it gives me an error message saying that the email address (which is the one I signed up with) is already in use / registered.  It says that if it belongs to me I should visit the account recovery page, which I did, and sent myself a recovery email, and signed in again, but the process repeated when I tried editing my about me afterward.  At one point I think I signed up for a stack exchange account with the same email, but when I tried signing in it said there was no account registered with that email so I created a new one, and now I'm running into this problem.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You had two accounts on the system (with the same email address).

I have merged these, so you should be able to log in now and update your details.

Comment: Thank you for your help :)